# Extract portion of filename with Regex in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, file, match, glob

I have a directory of files in the file system:

```
111111.222.log
222222.33.log
444444.0.log
```

If I have access to a variable `$id`, where `$id` is the first part of numbers before the first `.`, how do I get the second part of the number?

`$id` is a known value, the `$unknown` second part of the number is what I want to extract from the filename if it exists.

Is there some efficient approach to get this done without saving the entire directory of files into array, then go through each element with `split`?

What I have in mind is something like:

```
if (-e '$id.(\d+).log') {
    $unknown = $1;
}
```

The above is not a valid code, just an idea.

In reverse, if I have access to the full string, the regex I'm using for the extraction is (where `22` is `$unknown`):

```
"158855.22.log" =~ /^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.log$/;
print "ID is $1\n";
print "Unknown is $2\n";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine `glob` with regex matching:

```
foreach my $filename (glob "$id.*.log")
{
    if ($filename =~ /^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.log$/)
    {
        print "ID is $1\n";
        print "Unknown is $2\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works.  I'm testing it with the script in the same directory as the .log files. However, If I specify a search `$path = "/path/";` and put it before `$id`,  it stops working.  Is there a different way to assign the search path?

Comment: @KDX, What's the absolute path to the directory with the files you are testing?

Comment: It's `/home/kdx/data/log/` where I have the files.  If I place the script inside the directory along with the files, it works.  If I place the script outside of the directory, even with path specified, it doesn't work.  It seems like glob is doing its work on the current working directory only.

Comment: It's hard to know what you mean by *doesn't work*.  However, the regex will not match your path, because the regex matches: 1) the start of the string, 2) followed by a digit, one or more times.  Adding a path at the start of the string presumably means there's no digit immediately after the start of the string.  Get rid of the `^` at the beginning of the regex--then the regex will read: 1) Somewhere in the string find a digit, one or more times, 2) followed by a period, 3) followed by..

Comment: I find the workaround by using `use Cwd;` to change my current working directory to where the files are located.  Using the exact same code provided in the Answer, then change it back to the original working directory when finished processing.

Comment: @7stud Your suggestion works. I can now get rid of the `Cwd` module, simplified my workaround approach!  No need to change the current working directory.